# How do I use < symbol in my EF DefiningQuery SQL?

Tags: sql, entity-framework

With EntityFramework, I use the `<DefiningQuery>` element to define the SQL that represents my model. When I hand-edit the .edmx file to code the SQL, I cannot use expressions that include the `less than` sign without breaking the XML doc:

`WHERE SomeDate <= myColumnName`

The XML doc is breaking because the parser thinks this is the start of a new tag. How could I encode the `>` symbol in the edmx file to ensure that the project compiles AND that the SQL runs as expected at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the appropriate entities for `<` and `>`, which are `&lt;` and `&gt;` respectively:

`WHERE SomeDate &lt;= myColumnName`

Answer (score 1):

I think Better way would be to enclose the query in CDATA tags.

For example: `<![CDATA[select id, name from customers where salary > 1000]]>`

Answer (score 0):

You wrote faster than me :p
If you use the entities Brian says, the parser will convert them to the character they represent, so you'll have your "less than" symbol.